# Extract a string and replace it with something between $$

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a a long string created after parsing a file and any time I encounter $$ 1903810948 $$, I need to strip the numbers from between the $$ and save it separately and remove the $$ from the string. I am trying to use regex but cannot seem to figure out a way do it in python.

Edit: The string is basically parsed from a PDF file and it has special characters to the start and end of which is either a $ or a $$. I need to remove the contents from the file and create a separate file where I will store whatever I removed. That is why I do not think split is the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) method which splits a string into a list.

**Syntax**

> `string.split(separator, maxsplit)`

**Parameter Values**

1. ***separator*** : Optional. Specifies the separator to use when splitting the string. By default any whitespace is a separator .
2. **maxsplit** : Optional. Specifies how many splits to do. Default value is -1, which is "all occurrences".

**Here's a solution**

```
text = '$$ 1903810948 $$ 
print(text.split("$$")[1].split()[0])
```

**output**

```
 1903810948
```

To remove the white space use Split() without parameters

```
print(text.split("$$")[1].split()[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `replace()`, no need for regex.

```
string = '$$ 1903810948 $$'
print(string.replace('$',''))
```

Also this will give a little whitespace in the start and end of the string. This should fix that.

```
print(string.replace('$','')[1:-1])
```

output

```
1903810948
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex may not be the best option here as replace would work quite well.

However if you wish to use regex you can use

```
import re

string = '$$ 1903810948 $$'
pattern = r'\$\$ (\d+) \$\$'

re.findall(pattern, string)
#['1903810948']
```